# Backup/Restore Core Data with iCloud iOS7

Tags: core-data, ios7, backup, icloud, restore

I am trying to create an iCloud backup of my core data database in my application.  I would like to be able to save a 'snapshot' of the database to iCloud and then restore that snapshot to another device that installs the application.

On a side note: I've gotten iCloud syncing to work, but was having problems dealing with duplicate entries, something I can't have in my application.  So to work around this I was hoping to just backup the database with the option of restoring it later.

Thanks!

Comment: You can implement a method to go through the database, look for duplicates, and remove all but one of the duplicates. Should not be too difficult

Answer (score 0):

Saving "snapshots" of your Core Data database to iCloud is not its intended purpose so you are looking to swim upstream.

Having said that, to create a snapshot you could create a second persistent store, connect that second store to iCloud and then copy your current data into it.  This is in lieu of connecting iCloud to your primary store.

I would not recommend doing this.

Another option would be to use iCloud document storage instead and store a copy of your SQLite file there instead of using iCloud Core Data syncing.  This gives you more control over what and when you deal with this snapshot.

However, it would be better to solve your duplicates problem instead and then use iCloud syncing as it intended.

Comment: In dealing with the duplicates, is there any way to intercept the synced data before it is inserted locally?  I've listened for the NSPersistentStroeCoordinatorSotresWillChangeNotification, but it doesn't get hit.  I only get the DidChange notification.